# Proof for when $x^{-n}+y^{-n}=z^{-n}$, $x$ and $y$ can't be coprime?

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if x, y, z and n are positive integers and 
$$x^{-n}+y^{-n}=z^{-n}$$
then $$gcd(x,y)>1$$

I've been at this problem for a while. I believe the situation can be reduced to n=1 and n=2, because of Fermat's last theorem. For too long I actually thought it would reduce it to n=1 and that's why I tried a lot of messing around with that particular case. When looking at what has been discussed about the case n=1, it seemed like instead of proving that gcd(x,y)=1, they modified the equation to make it so (because it wasn't the main interest).

This assignment was given in our first number theory course (divisibility, prime numbers, congruence, chinese remainder theorem, quadratic reciprocity law etc)  at university. I feel like it might be some simple thing I'm missing, but maybe that feeling comes up often when looking at number theory problems.

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Note that you don't need to consider any cases other than $n=1$...

Comment: Seems it is wrong since $(x^n, y^n)=1$ does not implies  $n=1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any cases other than $n=1$, because $(x,y)=1$ if and only if $(x^n,y^n)=1$.

Now if $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{z}$$ then $$(x+y)z=xy$$

But if $(x,y)=1$ show that $(x+y,xy)=1$. This is relatively easy.

A fun way to prove this is that the polynomial $p(w)=w^2-(x+y)w+xy$ has roots $w=x$ and $w=y$. But if $d=\gcd(x+y,xy)$ then $$ 0=p(x)\equiv x^2\pmod{d}\\0=p(y)\equiv y^2\pmod{d}$$

So $x^2$ and $y^2$ have a common factor, $d$, which contradicts $x,y$ being relatively prime if $d>1$.

A sick brute force approach is, if $(x,y)=1$ then we can find integers $a,b$ so that $ax+by=1$. Then:

$$(x+y)\left[a^2x+b^2y\right]-xy(a-b)^2=(ax+by)^2=1$$

So $x+y$ and $xy$ are relatively prime.

(There are much easier ways to show that $(x+y,xy)=1$ if $(x,y)=1$.)

Comment: My brain seems to be too much of a mush at the moment to understand this properly. I'll come back to it later this week, as soon as I can. Really want to understand it because I already wasted too much time on it. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

If

$$ \frac{1}{x^n} + \frac{1}{y^n} = \frac{x^n + y^n}{x^n y^n} $$

is the reciprocal of some integer, then it follows that $ x^n + y^n $ divides $ x^n y^n $. It follows that the prime divisors of $ x^n + y^n $ are a subset of the prime divisors of $ x^n y^n $; but if $ x $ and $ y $ are coprime, no such prime can divide $ x^n + y^n $. It follows that $ x^n + y^n = \pm 1 $, which is impossible if both $ x, y $ are positive integers.